# Send single monitor to sleep

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have mutliple monitors, but often i do not need all of them. So i want to send them to sleep mode one by one when the mouse has not moved on the screen for a period of time. So my question is how it is possible to send a single monitor to sleep?

I already tried this but with not luck: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12794/Complete-Guide-on-How-To-Turn-A-Monitor-On-Off-Sta
It will always send all screens to sleep.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hWnd = NativeMethods.FindWindow(this.Text);

    NativeMethods.MonitorOff(hWnd);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    NativeMethods.MonitorOn(hWnd);
}

private static class NativeMethods
{
    internal static void MonitorOn(IntPtr? hWnd = null)
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd ?? HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (IntPtr)MONITOR_ON);
    }

    internal static void MonitorOff(IntPtr? hWnd = null)
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd ?? HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (IntPtr)MONITOR_OFF);
    }

    internal static IntPtr FindWindow(string lpWindowName)
    {
        return FindWindow(null, lpWindowName);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    private static int MONITOR_ON = -1;
    private static int MONITOR_OFF = 2;
    private static int MONITOR_STANBY = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// the message is sent to all top-level windows in the system
    /// </summary>
    private static IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
    /// <summary>
    /// the message is sent to one top-level window in the system
    /// </summary>
    private static IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);

    private static UInt32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    private static IntPtr SC_MONITORPOWER = new IntPtr(0xF170);
}
```

Comment: Given that this deals with the power management features, and there's no feature to control power management for individual monitors, I'm afraid your only option is the "power off" button on teh monitor. Maybe your monitor has an off-timer? No real way to prevent the turn-off or wake the monitor back again with moving the mouse, though.

Comment: I implemented a function using SetVCPFeature but it doesn't appear to work on my monitor - possibly it isn't supported on all monitors?

Answer (score 0):

From the way your question is phrased, you don't actually want to send the screens to sleep, you just want to stop sending a signal to them. That means it depends on your setup.
If you have a setup where each monitor has its own port on your PC, this should be doable by just turning the respective HDMI/VGA/DP port off. Note that this does mean it's probably not possible to wake the screen back up (or in this case, resume sending data) by just moving the mouse pointer there.
If you have a setup where your PC somehow doesn't have a port for each screen, this is likely not possible.

Long story short, the kind of sleep you want is impossible, it's only possible to cut the signal off.

Comment: I found the [MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) which can /TurnOff and /TurnOn any monitor. Does the tool cut of the signal?
To make it easy for me, I will only trigger the tool to enable or disable the screens.

Comment: I actually don't know how it works internally, but that seems to do what you asked for.